# Kelvin to Celsius conversion on multiple ASC files

Tags: python, type-conversion, temperature

I have 1,095 ASC files that each have and 8x8 table of kelvin temperatures. I need to convert all of these to celsius. All files are stored under one folder and each needs to be converted.
I know how to convert the values but I don't know how to do it in python.

There are many mathematical calculations in this code that I am running, would it be easier to make the conversion at the math part of the code instead of changing all the files prior?

I have tried to do a basic -273.15 subtraction from the kelvin to celsius but I can't figure out how to do it for all of my files.

Comment: What are ASC files?

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with? There are many tutorials on how to read and write files in Python.